# Google Apps won't receive PHP mail() emails

Tags: php, linux, apache, google-app-engine, email

From [this](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55299) support thread in google. I believe this is the problem :

"Because your website and your Google Apps email address share the same domain name, the mail agent running on the server that hosts your website thinks that it is responsible for mail addressed to your domain name. This is a typical default setting.
When someone submits the form on your website, the mail agent recognizes your domain name and concludes that it should be sending mail to itself. The mail agent will attempt to deliver the message locally."

Where should I look at to resolve this, is it a PHP or Apache issue?

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two basic options:

- Configure your sendmail (or replacement) to send all mail directly to Google's SMTP server with your account information. This is what the `mail()` function is using.
- Skip sendmail and let PHP connect directly over SMTP to your Google SMTP account.  Use a library like phpMailer to make it easy.

Comment: Thank you @Matt S, would [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/65365/disable-local-delivery-in-sendmail) also be a viable solution ?

Comment: Yes, that's similar to my first option. Just make sure you're not incidentally running a public open relay (taking any random internet requests and forwarding every mail to Google).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Matt S, his solution works well for Google Apps mail when the web server itself has been blacklisted by Google.  I've had this before, didn't matter what filters were set up in Google Apps mail, it spammed anything received from that server.

However, your quote in the question relates to the mailserver on the server your site is hosted on. If you are setup to use Google Apps but your mailserver is still turned on (in Plesk it's in Services->Mail) then you won't receive that email. So turn off the mailserver first, if that fails do as Matt S suggests.